# Spread by matched factor levels in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I have matched pairs of a factor that I would like to split into two separate columns. More specifically, I have six individuals (`individual_code`) that were measured (`mean_mass`)twice, so each individual is represented twice in the `individual_code` column. I would like to have generate two separate mass columns (one for each measurement).

Here is a subset of my data:

```
therm_sen_data %>%
  filter(storage_temp == '7') %>%
  subset(select = c("individual_code", "mean_mass")) %>%
  head(12) %>%
  dput

structure(list(individual_code = structure(c(3L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 
11L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 11L, 6L), .Label = c("852", "858", "860", 
"876", "879", "881", "883", "893", "908", "927", "940", "945"
), class = "factor"), mean_mass = c(2.07505, 1.3784, 1.19775, 
2.1316, 1.29995, 1.60015, 2.065, 1.36275, 1.1702, 2.1384, 1.3014, 
1.6056)), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've used `tidyr::spread` on similar problems before, but `spread(individual_code, mean_mass)` generates an error because of (I assume) the duplicates within `individual_code`:

```
Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 12 rows:
* 1, 7
* 4, 10
* 3, 9
* 6, 12
* 2, 8
* 5, 11
```

Is there an aspect to `spread` that I'm missing, or will I need something besides this function to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the document of `spread`, it says *Development on spread() is complete, and for new code we recommend switching to pivot_wider(), which is easier to use, more featureful, and still under active development*.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(individual_code) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = mean_mass) %>%
  ungroup

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   individual_code   `1`   `2`
#   <fct>           <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 860              2.08  2.06
# 2 893              1.38  1.36
# 3 879              1.20  1.17
# 4 876              2.13  2.14
# 5 940              1.30  1.30
# 6 881              1.60  1.61
```

Comment: The syntax for pivot_wider() is a lot more intuitive too - thanks. However, I'm still getting an error. It seems to be something with mutate(). ```Error: row_number() should only be called in a data context```

Comment: Ah, looks like another library I had running was the issue.

``` 
dplyr::mutate(id = row_number())
```

works just fine. I'll mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

a `data.table` oneliner

```
library( data.table )
dcast( setDT(df), individual_code ~ rowid(individual_code), value.var = "mean_mass" )

#    individual_code       1       2
# 1:             860 2.07505 2.06500
# 2:             876 2.13160 2.13840
# 3:             879 1.19775 1.17020
# 4:             881 1.60015 1.60560
# 5:             893 1.37840 1.36275
# 6:             940 1.29995 1.30140
```